# How to share Power BI datamart structure between organizations

Tags: powerbi

I work for an ERP company that is creating Power BI reports for multiple customers. All of their customers share the same SQL databse structure. However, each customer has it's own seperate SQL databse.

How would I be able to create a Power BI datamart that uses our ERP SQL structure and then share the datamart structure to each customer for them to connect it to their own SQL server?

I'm not sure that it is possible, but I wanted to ask.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is a good use for Power BI [Template Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-template-apps-overview). Per the Power BI [blog](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/insights-made-easy-with-power-bi-template-apps/), "template Apps are integrated packages of pre-built Power BI dashboards and reports, configured to connect to specific data sources."